# Factores de Expansión Encuesta CASEN 2017 en R

Tags: r, rstudio, stata

Estoy trabajando con la encuesta CASEN 2017 en Chile, la cual cuenta con factores de expansión entre sus variables **expr**. En STATA, al momento de ponderar por esta variable, se debía incluir el comando `fweight`. Por ejemplo, para la variable *sexo* tenia el comando `tabstat sexo [fweight = expr], statistics( count ) by(sexo)` obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

| Sexo | N |
| --- | --- |
| Hombre | 8469711 |
| Mujer | 9337703 |

Ahora, necesito llegar al mismo resultado pero con **"R"**.

Tengo el siguiente código `casen %>% group_by(sexo) %>% summarise(sum(sexo))`, pero no he logrado aplicar el factor de expansión, y estoy obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

| Sexo | N |
| --- | --- |
| Hombre | 103322 |
| Mujer | 226234 |

En STATA obtengo lo mismo al no aplicar el factor de expansión.

La base de datos está disponible en: http://observatorio.ministeriodesarrollosocial.gob.cl/encuesta-casen-2017

Entonces, en resumen, la ayuda que solicito es cómo aplicar los factores de expansión en **R**

Comment: ¡Hola! Para poder ayudarte mejor resultaría conveniente que explicases un poco más cómo son tus datos (si pones `dput(nombre_objeto)` en R y copias el resultado, podemos ver el aspecto de tus datos), qué es exactamente el factor de expansión y cómo quieres utilizarlo, . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que una `frequency weight` es ponderar la frecuencia según cierto valor, por lo que cada fila en definitiva se multiplicaría por este ponderador. Según tu ejemplo sería simplemente algo así:

```
casen %>% 
  group_by(sexo) %>% 
  summarise(sum(expr))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
        sexo `sum(expr)`
   <dbl+lbl>       <dbl>
1 1 [Hombre]     8469711
2 2 [Mujer]      9337703
```

Por cierto, la frecuencia, normalmente, no se calcula usando `sum()` por que en este caso, lo que estarías haciendo es sumando un factor (sexo), que vale 1 para `Hombre` y 2 para `Mujer`.  En todo caso podrías hacer `casen %>% group_by(sexo) %>% summarise(n = n())` para obtener las frecuencias, o si usas `sum()` en todo caso haría `casen %>% group_by(sexo) %>% summarise(sum(1))`